# getter not able to access it's value after being set

Tags: java

I have a login page and after the user enters their credentials -> they get validated in the api and from the api information I set the values of a user object

I use a setter method

```
XVL.user.setFirstName("first name")
```

I made sure it works well...

and then it changes the view

once it changes the view

```
XVL.user.getFirstName();
```

returns undefined, and it's not being reset at any point.

the user object is created at startup

```
public static void startup()
{
...
    user = new User();
}
```

and is defined statically

```
static public User user;
```

the following is the user class

```
package package name

import java.util.Date;

public class User
{
  public User()
  {
    super();
  }

  private String firstName;


  public String getFirstName()
  {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName)
  {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
}
```

is it because it's static that it's only temporarily being saved from the setters? I checked in the debugger and even when it's saying undefined in the global variables it seems defined...

Comment: Let's see the user class' method `User::setFirstName`

Comment: Show the class User or the method get and set of the firstName

Comment: @ifly6 I posted that for you now

Comment: Are you sure `XVL.user` not modifying from somewhere else in between XVL.user.setFirstName("first name")  and XVL.user.getFirstName(); call

Comment: @AmitBera yes I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time, it turned out to be something unrelated to the user object that was causing the error, a bit frustrating to look in the wrong place... but at least I can sleep assured that after 5 years in a software engineering degree I do know how to use objects properly :-)